# How to avoid plain text passwords in a python script?

Tags: python, security, cryptography, passwords, password-protection

I am going to start a new python project with web **scraping**, data analysis and etc... This implies making some logins in emails and data websites. I would like to know how can I avoid putting plain text password in my python scripts? Because I understand this is not very secure to have your password readable somewhere.

I have found a method using cryptography library that encrypts your password and generates a secret key that can decrypt it but I think it is not a good idea because as soon as a put the secret key in the script, someone can decrypt my password.
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/encrypt-passwords-python-scripts-lee-rock/

Also, some people say to create a file named secret.py and stores there all passwords I need. When I have to use it, I can import this file and get the password. Consequently, this is not good too because there is a file full of readables passwords.

None of all these results were not satisfying.

In my case, I would like to share my code without leaking my passwords.

Comment: You can require the user to enter the decryption key when they run the script, instead of putting it in the script.

Comment: As the decryption key is very difficult to memorise, do you think there is a library that allows us to generate a passphrase as a decryption key? Being as safe as the other one? Or a passphrase is not a good idea?

Comment: Look here: https://pypi.org/project/keyring/

Comment: You could save the decryption key in a Shell variable that just exists on your computer.

Comment: Could you have your passwords stored in a plaintext file that is not stored in your code? For instance, if you're on mac/linux, your computer has a `~/.ssh/id_rsa` file. If you're doing an SSH thing, the SSH code will look for that file, but since it's outside of the directory, it won't be uploaded if you were to share your SSH code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing api keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56619034/storing-api-keys)

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/205606/strategy-for-keeping-secret-info-such-as-api-keys-out-of-source-control is another good reference

Comment: Oh I am using Windows 10. But I think the best ways you to, each time I run the code, it asks for the login and password, as said Barmar. So, there are only temporary variables in the RAM after the login is done, I will be erased. Do you think is the best way? The process will not be completely automatic but it will work.

Comment: This sort of question defintiely seems like a better fit for either softwareengineering.stackexchange.com or security.stackexchange.com.